# ReferenceError: isUndefined is not defined in angular-local-storage

Tags: angularjs, cordova, local-storage

I'm developing html 5 mobile app using visual studio cordova, angular js and ionic framework. In that, I need to save some values to localStorage. I followed some articles but there is an error throwing when saving values to the local storage.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
 <head>    <title>Test app</title></head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-local-storage.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic', 'LocalStorageModule']);

        myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'localStorageService', function ($scope, localStorageService) {

            $scope.test = function () {
                var storageType = localStorageService.getStorageType();
                console.log(storageType);
                localStorageService.set('test', 'val');
            }
        }]);
    </script>
    <div>
        <input type="button" ng-click="test()" value="add new">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It throws `ReferenceError: isUndefined is not defined at Object.addToLocalStorage`

Any idea??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a plunker working with your application [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4qNG3aeVxqN25LGlTNKH?p=preview)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic' ,'LocalStorageModule']).config(function(localStorageServiceProvider) {
localStorageServiceProvider
  .setPrefix('cars')
  .setStorageType('localStorage')
  .setNotify(false, false);
  }).controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'localStorageService', function ($scope, localStorageService) {

        $scope.test = function () {
            var storageType = localStorageService.getStorageType();
            console.log(storageType);
            localStorageService.set('test', 'val');
        }
    }]);
```

Comment: What was the actual problem and how did this solve it?

Comment: He actually added this: ```.config(function(localStorageServiceProvider) {
localStorageServiceProvider
  .setPrefix('cars')
  .setStorageType('localStorage')
  .setNotify(false, false);
  })```